# Homogeneous solution, Fourier mode, wavelength

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

> > Consider a system
> >     $$
> > \partial_t u=N(\sigma)u,~~u=(x,t)~~~(1)
> > $$
> >     where $N$ is a non-linear operator depending on some control parameter. Suppose that the system (1) **admits a homogeneous solution** $u=u_0$ and (1) undergoes a finite wavelength instability as $\sigma$ is varied, e.g. becomes positive. That is, if we consider evolution of the **Fourier mode** $\exp(ikx+\lambda t)$ the growth rate $Re(\lambda)$ behaves as follows: for $\sigma <0$, all modes are decaying $(Re(\lambda)<0)$ and the homogeneous solution $u_0$ is stable. For $\sigma=0$, a critical wavenumber $k_c$ gains neutral stability, and for $\sigma >0$, there is a narrow band of wavenumbers around $k_c$, where the growth rate $Re(\lambda)$ is positive.>>

There are some connections I do not understand. I am new into this.

(1) What is meant with homogeneous solution $u_0$ of (1)?

(2) From where do the Fourier modes come? How are they connected with the homogeneous solution $u_0$?

Maybe it is assumed that we can write $u_0=u_0(x,t)$ as
$$
u_0(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\tilde{u}(k)\, dk?
$$

(3) Why is $Re(\lambda)$ the growth rate (of what)?

(4) Why is the homogeneous solution stable if $Re(\lambda)<0$?

Comment: first write $u(x,0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i kx} U(k) dk$, if the system is linear then you'll have homogeneous solution $u(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i kx+ \omega(k) t} U(k) dk$ . if $\omega(k)$ is imaginary (for example $\omega = k c$ in the case of the wave equation) then the energy doesn't depend on $t$. if $Re(\omega(k)) < 0$ then the energy decreases exponentially, but if $Re(\omega(k)) > 0$  it ***grows*** exponentially.

Comment: so it depends on your non-linear operator, but when it is smooth enough, you can linearize it (locally) around $u(x,0)$ and see if the system is locally stable or oscillatory or non-stable, by looking at $sign(Re(\omega(k)))$

Comment: (1.) You mean "if $\omega(k)$ is real", or? (2.) $\omega(k)$ is the dispersion relation, right? What does the "energy" has to do with it? (3.) What exactly is meant by "homogeneous solution"?